# is it possible to have casperjs to click a specific region

Tags: frontend, casperjs

Is it possible to get casperjs to click a specific x, y position? I'm basically trying to interact with a canvas (clicking specific points on the canvas) but not sure how to go about doing this. If its not possible is there a front end library that can do this?

Thanks

Comment: frontend? casperjs is based on phantomjs, I am not sure whether there is a `click(x,y)` in casper.. but if you can access the phantom API it has: [SendEvent](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference-WebPage#sendeventmouseeventtype-mousex-mousey-buttonleft-or-sendeventkeyboardeventtype-keyorkeys-null-null-modifier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try accessing Phantom api:

```
casper.then(function() { 
    this.page.sendEvent(...)
});
```

Comment: how do you run phantomJs specific api in casperjs?

Comment: `casper.page` is a reference to PhantomJS WebPage. you should be able to do `casper.page.sendEvent("mouse..", ..)`

Answer (score 0):

CasperJS provides a `mouse` module that you can use to place a [`mouse.click`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/mouse.html#click) somewhere.

I would suggest to retrieve the canvas area first and then place the click relative to the canvas element. You can even have your own function like that:

```js
casper.relativeClick = function(selector, x, y){
    var info = this.getElementInfo(selector);
    if (x < info.width && y < info.height) {
        x += info.x;
        y += info.y;
        this.mouse.click(x, y);
    } else {
        console.log("warning: click out of bounds");
    }
}
```

You can then invoke it inside a step (`then*` or `wait*`).